# I don’t understand: CS50 prime

Tags: c, cs50

Consider *[Prime](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/prime/)* ([CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50)) from lecture 1.

I need to find prime numbers from 1-100 by using:

- Practice using *for* loops
- Using modulo
- Creating a Boolean function

I realised how to solve the problem already and where I went wrong, but I don't understand why.

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

bool prime(int number);

int main(void)
{
    int min;
    do
    {
        min = get_int("Minimum: ");
    }
    while (min < 1);

    int max;
    do
    {
        max = get_int("Maximum: ");
    }
    while (min >= max);

    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (prime(i))
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
        }
    }
}

// Print only prime numbers in the range.
// It takes in int number, and outputs bool true or false

bool prime(int number)
{
    // 1 is not prime, 2 is prime
    if (number < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        // not prime
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // is prime
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return number; // has an output
}
```

This was my original answer, but it was just printing odd numbers. My program worked after removing the

```
// is prime
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
```

But I don’t really understand. Why?

Comment: Simply, the `else` was causing the loop to terminate prematurely.

Comment: You can't decide if a number is prime or not without checking all of the possible divisors. With that return the loop would only execute one iteration.

Comment: Note that the line `return number;` at the end of the function should be `return true;`. It happens to work because the function returns early if `number` is less than 2, and any non-zero integer is considered `true` when converted to a `bool`.

Comment: Look at the logic of your loop.  On the first iteration, it checks if the number is even, i.e., if it's divisible by 2.  If it is, it returns false.  Otherwise it returns true.  It never makes it to the second loop iteration.  Obviously that makes no sense.  To fix it, get rid of the `else` and instead unconditionally return true *outside* of the loop, after it exits.

Comment: There is [a whole Stack Exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/tour) dedicated to [Harvard CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50).

Answer (score 2):

> my program worked after removing the `else { return true; }`
> i dont really understand why, can someone explain?

Consider the `for` loop below.  On the first iteration, code *returns* when `number % i == 0` is true and when it is `false`.

```
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        // not prime
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        // is prime
        else { 
            return true;
        }

       // Code never reaches this point.
    }
```

By removing the 2nd return path, the loop can iterate again.

---

**Other improvements**

- No need to iterate [2...number).  About to the square root of `number` is sufficient.  Code goes from [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to O(sqrt(n)) - much faster.
- Easy to handle all even numbers as a special case.  Then our loop runs 2x.

```
bool prime(int number) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
      return number == 2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= number/i; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return number > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The technical definition of a prime number is a number that has two multiples and those are 1 and itself. To check if a certain number is prime, you loop through all the numbers less the test number, and then you attempt to divide the test number with each of those numbers and check the remainder. If the remainder is 0 then you break and return a false for the function. A trivial implementation of this in C is shown below.

```
// Import the libraries at the top of the file
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(int k) {
  // Initialize a return type
  bool prime = true;

  // 0 and 1 are already disqualified
  if(k==0 || k==1) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    // Check from 2
    for(int i=2; i<k; i++) {

      // Divide the test number with the numbers less than it
      if(k%i == 0) {
        // 'k' is not prime, update return type and break
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    // Return a true or false to the calling function
    return prime;
  }
}
```

To get all the prime numbers less than 100, you need a loop and the function we have implemented above.

```
int main() {
  // Define a variable to count how many prime numbers you have so far
  int counter = 0;

  // Loop from 0 to 200 and print the numbers
  for(int i=0; i<200; i++) {
    // If 'counter' is equal to 100 then we are done
    if(counter == 100) {
      break;
    }

    // Use the prime function to check
    if(isPrime(i)) {

      // Increment the counter
      counter += 1;

      // Print the number to the console
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }

  // Return an exit code to the operating system
  return 0;
}
```